# ASP.Net SQL Where Date is after Today

Tags: asp.net, sql

Hi all I have the following Query made using the Query Builder in Visual Studio.

```
SELECT Schd_ID, Schd_Date, Schd_Avaliable, Schd_Nights, Schd_Price, Accom_ID
FROM   Schedule
WHERE  (Schd_Avaliable = 'Yes') AND (Accom_ID = Accom_ID)
```

I want to add another WHERE statement which adds where Schd_Date is after todays date, any ideas?

Comment: What RDBMS and version? What datatype is `Schd_Date`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is SQL Server you could use the [`GETDATE()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188383.aspx) function to return the current date and compare against it:

```
SELECT 
    Schd_ID, Schd_Date, Schd_Avaliable, Schd_Nights, Schd_Price, Accom_ID 
FROM 
    Schedule 
WHERE 
    (Schd_Avaliable = 'Yes') 
AND 
    (Accom_ID = Accom_ID)
AND 
    (Schd_Date > GETDATE())
```

Comment: sorry for the duplicate answer. you must have posted this, when I was writing the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming SQL Server, the GETDATE() function returns the date **and time** the statement was run at:

```
WHERE Schd_Date > GETDATE()
```

Use the following for finding dates greater than the current date at midnight:

```
WHERE Schd_Date > DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()))
```

However, `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` is the ANSI means of getting the current date and time in a database.  Beyond that, date functionality is not consistent between databases so you'd have to tell us what you are dealing with for better answers.

Comment: +1 This was a more efficient and cleaner way to produce the same result as I intended with my solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Schd_ID, Schd_Date, Schd_Avaliable, Schd_Nights, Schd_Price, Accom_ID
FROM   Schedule
WHERE  (Schd_Avaliable = 'Yes') AND (Accom_ID = Accom_ID) AND (GETDATE() < Schd_Date)
```

This should work

Answer (score 0):

I guess this expression can be used as a date representing the current date on the format *yyyy-mm-dd* (without the hours,minutes and seconds).

`(Datepart('yyyy',getdate())+ '-' +Datepart('m',getdate())+ '-' + Datepart('d',getdate()))`

therefore

```
SELECT Schd_ID, Schd_Date, Schd_Avaliable, Schd_Nights, Schd_Price, Accom_ID 
FROM   Schedule    
WHERE  (Schd_Avaliable = 'Yes') AND (Accom_ID = Accom_ID) AND 
       (Schd_Date >= (Datepart('yyyy',getdate())+ '-' + 
                     Datepart('m',getdate())+ '-' + 
                     Datepart('d',getdate())))
```

Comment: `DATEPART` returns `int`, which has a higher priority than `varchar` when the two types are mixed in a single expression. So the engine would attempt to interpret `'-'` as an integer and fail, naturally. Conclusion: you need to convert the result of each `DATEPART` to a string.

Comment: @Andriy: You are of course right. I will delete this answer since  OMG Ponies' answer is more efficient and better (this is even further emphasized by the fact that I would have to add the correct CAST or CONVERT call to make the messy logic work.